# Follow up to Carl Sagan’s "Contact" with a character deciphering pi

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading the back cover of a novel some years ago that described itself as a kind of unofficial follow up to Carl Sagan Contact novel. I remember something about the original message translator/researcher (Maybe Ellie in Contact?) being old and (maybe near her death?) and maybe her granddaughter picking up the slack with the deciphering of pi or a new message.

I'm sorry if I'm being vague last time I saw that book was many years ago and never got to read it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about approximately what year this would have been?  (e.g. late 90s)

Comment: Note that finding a message in the base-11 digits of pi is _part_ of the novel *Contact*.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104660/patterns-in-pi-in-contact